# Trying to run a Script File using bash for the first time

Tags: bash, scripts

Please I am trying to execute a `.sh` file and I am getting

Already set `chmod -x test.sh`

Did `chmod u+x test.sh`, but still...

> Command not found!

```
./test.sh: line 1: hello: command not found
```

please any help...

Comment: Can you edit your first post with the content of the file `test.sh` ? If you want to display "hello" you need to write `echo "hello"`

Comment: Can you post your script? (Use pastebin if needed)

Answer (score 1):

Try the old school way:

a - chmod 777 YourScript.sh

b - edit your script and make line 1:

(pound bang) /usr/bin/bash

You can determine the path to bash with 'which bash'.

c - finally, as previously indicated, make this test version simple like:

echo "hi"

hth, Matt